# How can I generate a command for start-stop-daemon that will kill the process if it doesn't term during a timeout period?

Tags: linux, daemon, redis, start-stop-daemon

I need to run a `start-stop-daemon` for a redis instance and I want it to send a `SIGTERM` and if the redis instance doesn't quit i would like it to force a quit.

The `start-stop-daemon` configuration says that the `--retry` option can be used for that but i couldn't figure a way to do this, here's my current command:

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --retry forever/TERM --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/redis/redis.pid --exec /usr/bin/redis-server
```

Any hints on how I would be able to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways:

The first is just to specify a numeric `--retry` value. Then it will use `/signal/timeout/KILL/timeout` schedule. I.e. send a terminating signal (specified with `--signal` option), then wait the specified number of seconds and then send a KILL signal that could not be ignored by a process and therefore it will be forced to exit.
The command will look like:

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --signal TERM --retry 5 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/redis/redis.pid --exec /usr/bin/redis-server
```

The second is to specify a complete *schedule* to the `--retry option`. It will look like:

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --stop --retry TERM/5/KILL/10 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/redis/redis.pid --exec /usr/bin/redis-server
```